# How to implement multi root functionality using CKEditor 5?

Tags: angular, rich-text-editor, ckeditor5

Our Angular 10 application requires Rich text editing of columns, and as per the requirement, the multi root functionality offered by CKEditor 5 seems the best option.

But as per their documentation, we need to create our own custom build to achieve the multi root functionality. Even the online build feature, provided by CKEditor team, doesn't gives the option to support multi editors.

Is there any other option, rather than creating our own custom build to get the multi root functionality?

Any help/suggestion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, CKEditor 5 does not offer a ready-to-use multi-root editor yet. However, such an editor can be implemented by using the CKEditor 5 Framework. Check out the “Implementing a custom editor creator” guide which contains the source code of the demo below.